# How can i run MySQL and MariaDB database server at the same time and access them at phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, mariadb

First i want to have two different database servers on Windows 10

A MySQL database server and a MariaDB database server

Second; I want to be able to access them at Phpmyadmin (On Phpmyadmin login screen, I am expecting to see 'Servers' dropdown list to pick either MySQL Server or MariaDB server)

How can I achieve this on Windows 10 ?

Comment: Are they configured to run via TCP/IP on different ports?

Answer (score 0):

**1**. It's posible, for run mysql and mariadb, u need config one **instance** more, because mysql and mariadb have similar core. (Is same to install two mysql server instance in one machine). Here one tutorial for install instances of mysql on windows. [Multiple MySQL Instances on Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-windows-servers.html)

**2**. phpmyadmin requires a web server, PHP, and a browser. But... i think that isn't possible, because this is connect **simultaneously to two database server** via only one connection of phpmyadmin in your browser, and *i think* isn't logic support. I think that u can try is install **two** phpmyadmin. One for mysql and other for mariadb. Check docs in the web site, maybe u can obtain other solution. [Phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

Regards ✌️